# How to set alarm?

Tags: alarm

How can I set alarm in my android phone? My phone is SYMPHONY Xplorer W35. Android Version: Jelly Bean 4.1.1

I can set alarm through many apps. For example in my phone there is a app called "Clock". Is there any built in process by which I can set up alarm??

Answer (score 2):

Clock is the standard application for alarms. In Android, pretty much every feature is an Application, and one application can be replaced by the other.